# Binding a treeview to a list and group the items in function of a property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

Here's a simplified version of what I have :

```
class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GameServer { get; set; }
}
```

And i'd like to get a TreeView from a list of theses accounts, and group them by server, like this :

[image: Tree]

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for code without trying it yourself. I dont think such behavior is gladly welcome here. Anyways I will gladly spam you with links that you could have found yourself on the internet.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/simple-treeview/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/treeview-in-wpf/

Check them out.

**EDIT:**

For HierarchicalDataTemplate see this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx

**EDIT 2:**

If you wish to use grouping function. Read this:
http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

Comment: I tried. My problem is that I need to bind this list, and I don't have a "hierarchical" code to be able to use HierarchicalDataTemplate. 
So i'm looking for a way to "sort" my objets in the treeview by the GameServer property. Sorry if my question was unclear

Comment: That is why you should tell us exactly about your problem and post us code. I will edit my question. Check the new link out. Its easy

Comment: Thank you but it's not exactly my problem. I don't have a Server class wich contains a list of Account, but just a list of Account wich i want to "sort" in the tree view by the name of the server.

Comment: You dont need a TreeView for that. You could do so in a ListBox with GroupingDescription. Let me edit my answer again for you.